# Condição IF dentro de um SELECT Oracle

Tags: java, android, oracle

Há outras perguntas neste contexto, porém sou leigo no assunto e não entendo.
Com isto, preciso de ajuda.

Tenho um `SELECT` para busca de dados em um banco de dados `ORACLE`, porém preciso fazer uma condição `IF` dentro deste `SELECT`.

Exemplo:

Tenho o seguinte `SELECT`:

```
SELECT
CAMPO1, CAMPO2, CAMPO3, CAMPO4, CAMPO5
FROM
TABELA1
WHERE
CAMPO1 = dado1 AND CAMPO2 = dado2
```

A condição seria assim:

```
IF CAMPO1 IS NULL, CAMPO1 = CAMPO3
```

Existe a possibilidade de fazer essa condição dentro deste `SELECT`?
Ja pesquisei isto, achei alguns exemplos, porém não consegui entender.

Se alguém puder me ajudar.

Comment: Armando Marques Sobrinho, sei que é duplicata, porém como mencionei, não consegui entender e preciso de ajuda.  Tenho pouco conhecimento em manipular Banco de Dados e com isto tenho certa dificuldade em entender.

Comment: WHERE CAMPO1 IS NULL AND CAMPO1 = CAMPO3. É isso o que você quer?

Comment: voce tambem pode fazer isso diretamente dentro da lista de campos do select, algor tipo `IF (CAMPO1 == 'NULL' THEN CAMPO1 = CAMPO2) as aliasdoif` depois vc pode usar esse campo "aliasdoif" como se ele fosse um campo normal da tabela

Comment: Ótimo, acredito que isto me ajuda.  Muito obrigado

Comment: Obs : Se campo1 for NULL qualquer comparação com ele e outro SEMPRE dará false.

Comment: Conseguiu  resolver seu problema?

Answer (score 4):

No select você pode usar CASE Ex:

```
SELECT
     CASE WHEN CAMPO1 IS NULL THEN 'CAMPO1 NULL' 
       ELSE CAMPO1 END AS CAMPO1, 
     CAMPO2, 
     CAMPO3, 
     CAMPO4, 
     CAMPO5
FROM TABELA1
WHERE CAMPO1 = dado1 AND CAMPO2 = dado2
```

Se bem entendi a pergunta, acho que é mais ou menos isso que quer.

Referência: [CASE ORACLE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm)

E tem também COALESCE, este retornará o primeiro dado não nulo do conjunto passado como parâmetro Ex:

```
SELECT
     COALESCE(CAMPO1,'CAMPO1 NULL') AS CAMPO1, 
     CAMPO2, 
     CAMPO3, 
     CAMPO4, 
     CAMPO5
 FROM TABELA1
 WHERE CAMPO1 = dado1 AND CAMPO2 = dado2
```

Referência [COALESCE ORACLE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions023.htm)