# Coluna que recebe um resultado caso a condição seja verdadeira

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, oracle, pl-sql

```
SELECT
DISTINCT P.CD_PACIENTE
, P.NM_PACIENTE
, DECODE (P.TP_SEXO, 'M', 'MASCULINO',
                     'F', 'FEMININO', 
                     'I', 'INDEFINIDO') SEXO

, TRUNC(P.DT_NASCIMENTO) DT_NASCIMENTO
, (SELECT FN_IDADE (P.DT_NASCIMENTO, 'a A / m M / d D' ) FROM DUAL) IDADE_PACIENTE
, A.CD_ATENDIMENTO
, A.DT_ATENDIMENTO
, (SELECT FN_IDADE (A.DT_ATENDIMENTO, 'a A / m M / d D' ) FROM DUAL) DIAS_INTERNADO
, PE.CD_PRESTADOR --PRESTADOR DO ATENDIMENTO
, PE.NM_PRESTADOR
, L.CD_LEITO --LEITO DO PACIENTE
, L.DS_LEITO
, UI.CD_UNID_INT                             CD_UNIDADE_INTERNACAO--UNIDADE DE INTERNAÇÃO VINCULADA A INTERNAÇÃO
, UI.DS_UNID_INT                             UNIDADE_INTERNACAO
, (SELECT S.NM_SETOR FROM SETOR S WHERE UI.CD_SETOR = S.CD_SETOR) AS SETOR_UNIDADE_INTERNACAO --SETOR DA UNIDADE DE INTERNAÇÃO
, E.CD_ESPECIALID                            CD_ESPEC_ATENDIMENTO--ESPECIALIDADE VINCULADA AO MÉDICO PRESTADOR DO ATENDIMENTO
, E.DS_ESPECIALID                            ESPEC_ATENDIMENTO
, NULL STATUS

FROM LEITO L
JOIN ATENDIME A     ON A.CD_LEITO         = L.CD_LEITO
JOIN UNID_INT UI    ON UI.CD_UNID_INT     = L.CD_UNID_INT
JOIN SETOR S        ON S.CD_SETOR         = UI.CD_SETOR
JOIN PACIENTE P     ON P.CD_PACIENTE      = A.CD_PACIENTE
JOIN ESP_MED EM     ON EM.CD_PRESTADOR    = A.CD_PRESTADOR --ESPECIALIDADE DO ATENDIMENTO
JOIN ESPECIALID E   ON E.CD_ESPECIALID    = A.CD_ESPECIALID --SE COLOCAR P.CD_PRESTADOR IRÁ RETORNAR MAIS RESULTADOS, POIS UM PRESTADOR PODE TER MAIS DE UMA ESPECIALIDADE.
JOIN PRESTADOR PE   ON PE.CD_PRESTADOR    = A.CD_PRESTADOR   

WHERE A.TP_ATENDIMENTO = 'I'
AND A.CD_MOT_ALT IS NULL
--AND A.CD_MULTI_EMPRESA
AND A.CD_ATENDIMENTO = 773
```

Quero que quando o código da `cd_unid_interncao=64 and cd_especialid=63` a coluna `STATUS` receba **1**; se não, **0**.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Condição IF dentro de um SELECT Oracle](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/187071/condi%c3%a7%c3%a3o-if-dentro-de-um-select-oracle)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como a condição é o resultado da comparação de mais de uma coluna você deverá fazer uso de um **searched case statement**, ou seja, um [Case When](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm):

[SQLFiddle - Exemplo online:](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1f375/2)

```
SELECT 
 (CASE WHEN cd_unid_interncao=64 and cd_especialid=63 THEN 1
   ELSE 0 
 END) Status
FROM Exemplo;
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> o Oracle pesquisa da esquerda para a direita até encontrar uma
>   ocorrência de condição verdadeira e retorna return_expr.
>
> Se nenhuma condição for considerada verdadeira e existir uma cláusula ELSE, o
>   Oracle retornará else_expr. Caso contrário, o Oracle retornará nulo.

**Exemplo:**

```
SELECT
DISTINCT P.CD_PACIENTE
, P.NM_PACIENTE
, DECODE (P.TP_SEXO, 'M', 'MASCULINO',
                     'F', 'FEMININO', 
                     'I', 'INDEFINIDO') SEXO

, TRUNC(P.DT_NASCIMENTO) DT_NASCIMENTO
, (SELECT FN_IDADE (P.DT_NASCIMENTO, 'a A / m M / d D' ) FROM DUAL) IDADE_PACIENTE
, A.CD_ATENDIMENTO
, A.DT_ATENDIMENTO
, (SELECT FN_IDADE (A.DT_ATENDIMENTO, 'a A / m M / d D' ) FROM DUAL) DIAS_INTERNADO
, PE.CD_PRESTADOR --PRESTADOR DO ATENDIMENTO
, PE.NM_PRESTADOR
, L.CD_LEITO --LEITO DO PACIENTE
, L.DS_LEITO
, UI.CD_UNID_INT                             CD_UNIDADE_INTERNACAO--UNIDADE DE INTERNAÇÃO VINCULADA A INTERNAÇÃO
, UI.DS_UNID_INT                             UNIDADE_INTERNACAO
, (SELECT S.NM_SETOR FROM SETOR S WHERE UI.CD_SETOR = S.CD_SETOR) AS SETOR_UNIDADE_INTERNACAO --SETOR DA UNIDADE DE INTERNAÇÃO
, E.CD_ESPECIALID                            CD_ESPEC_ATENDIMENTO--ESPECIALIDADE VINCULADA AO MÉDICO PRESTADOR DO ATENDIMENTO
, E.DS_ESPECIALID                            ESPEC_ATENDIMENTO
, (CASE WHEN cd_unid_interncao=64 and cd_especialid=63 THEN 1
   ELSE 0 
 END)                                        Status

FROM LEITO L
JOIN ATENDIME A     ON A.CD_LEITO         = L.CD_LEITO
JOIN UNID_INT UI    ON UI.CD_UNID_INT     = L.CD_UNID_INT
JOIN SETOR S        ON S.CD_SETOR         = UI.CD_SETOR
JOIN PACIENTE P     ON P.CD_PACIENTE      = A.CD_PACIENTE
JOIN ESP_MED EM     ON EM.CD_PRESTADOR    = A.CD_PRESTADOR --ESPECIALIDADE DO ATENDIMENTO
JOIN ESPECIALID E   ON E.CD_ESPECIALID    = A.CD_ESPECIALID --SE COLOCAR P.CD_PRESTADOR IRÁ RETORNAR MAIS RESULTADOS, POIS UM PRESTADOR PODE TER MAIS DE UMA ESPECIALIDADE.
JOIN PRESTADOR PE   ON PE.CD_PRESTADOR    = A.CD_PRESTADOR   

WHERE A.TP_ATENDIMENTO = 'I'
AND A.CD_MOT_ALT IS NULL
--AND A.CD_MULTI_EMPRESA
AND A.CD_ATENDIMENTO = 773
```

Comment: @Don'tPanic só um ponto de atenção, seria um `OR` não `AND`

Comment: Não tem como uma coluna ter os 2 valores.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Tem razão, não me atentei a pergunta, tinha visto apenas a resposta aqui, que aí no caso ele está usando apenas `cd_unid_interncao` no Case.

Comment: Já corrigi, obrigado pelo alerta, em uma primeira leitura da pergunta eu entendi que se tratava de uma mesma coluna

Comment: Funcionou exatamente como queria, muito obrigado a todos!